# Need help on Regex return values

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a regex question assigned by my instructor and he wants us to make all the return values true by changing the string value in the three declared variables. This is my first time doing a regex question and I wanted a little help if that's okay. I tried www.regexpal.com  but I didn't know how to use it. 
Could someone shed a little light on this topic as to how I begin to solve this? Thanks

Heres the following code:

```
public class RegexTester {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String regexSSN = "";   //TODO add a regex for Social Security Numbers

  String regex9000 = "";  //TODO add a regex for GGC 9000 numbers here

  String regexZipPlus4 = ""; //TODO add a regex for zip+4 zipcodes here

  System.out.println("All of the following tests shoule return true, "
    + "the negative tests are negated (meaning that they should "
    + "also return true)");

  System.out.println("192-192-5555".matches(regexSSN)); // the following tests should all match
  System.out.println("444-183-1212".matches(regexSSN)); 
  System.out.println("032-431-9375".matches(regexSSN)); 
  System.out.println("122-650-4343".matches(regexSSN)); 
  System.out.println("900012389".matches(regex9000)); 
  System.out.println("900112389".matches(regex9000)); 
  System.out.println("900012390".matches(regex9000));
  System.out.println("900050000".matches(regex9000)); 
  System.out.println("30043".matches(regexZipPlus4)); 
  System.out.println("30043-1234".matches(regexZipPlus4)); 

  System.out.println(); // the following codes print out true

  System.out.println(!"192-XYZ-5555".matches(regexSSN)); // the following tests should NOT match
  System.out.println(!"00-192-5555".matches(regexSSN)); 
  System.out.println(!"90005000".matches(regex9000));        // too short!
  System.out.println(!"900250000".matches(regex9000));       // must be 9000* or 9001*
  System.out.println(!"9002500001".matches(regex9000));      // to big
  System.out.println(!"9001FOO00".matches(regex9000));       // no alpha allowed
  System.out.println(!"30043-12345".matches(regexZipPlus4));  // too long 
  System.out.println(!"300430-1234".matches(regexZipPlus4));  // too long 
  System.out.println(!"30043-12".matches(regexZipPlus4));     // too short
  System.out.println(!"300FO-1234".matches(regexZipPlus4));   // no alpha allowed
  System.out.println(!"30043=1234".matches(regexZipPlus4));   // missing hyphen


 }

}
```

Comment: Basically: can you do my homework? Short answer: **no**.

Comment: Im not trying to get people to do my homework, I just need help with the question because I don't know how to solve it. Maybe instead of attacking me you can point me in the direction where I can solve it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ might be helpful for designing your regex strings

Comment: @xtremeslice I know it seems like you're being attacked but I want to reassure you that's not really what's happening here. The way you've presented the question isn't really the way SO operates. Start by attempting the just the first section, when you have a specific question about why your solution isn't working then come back and get help with that.

Comment: oh ok ill try to figure it out then. thanks

Comment: @Duck Also, check out the link Duck posted (regex101.com) - it really is super helpful.

Comment: Just added a step by step on how to do the SSN regex, Hopefully that will help you build the others. Regex101.com has a dictionary of terms in the bottom right you can use and it explains exactly what your regex is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with reading through [java.util.regex.Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). It contains all necessary information to complete the assignment. You need to clearly understand requirements when constructing your regex pattern. You can then convert those requirements into regex.

E.g., to match telephone number of the following format XXX-XXX-XXXX, where X is any number you need
3 digits followed by dash, followed by 3 digits, followed by another dash and then by 4 digits:

```
$\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$
```

Please note that when assigning this pattern to a Java string, you need to escape special characters.

I like using RegexPlanet to test my code. Here is a link for the fist problem: [regexSSN](http://fiddle.re/8evzu6) (although ssn should be 9 digit long, in your code it's 10). Click on Go button. You will be able to enter your test cases.

Here's the solution for your fist case.

```
String regexSSN = "^(\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}\\-\\d{4})";
```

Hopefully this will get you started so you can complete other two problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! god bless.

Answer (score 0):

When designing regex strings, I like to begin by categorizing parts of the string into similar components. Lets take the SSN regex as an example.

Step 1: We see the format is `###-###-#####` where # is a number 0-9

Step 2: The regex for matching a number is either `[0-9]` or `\d`

Step 3: Now we can write it out in regex `\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d` where `-` is just a literal dash.

Step 4: Notice repetition? We can take care of that too with `{n}` where `n` is the number of time we want to repeat the previous section, so now we have `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

And thats how you do SSN Regex.

Comment: Thanks! I actually was reading my book and because I am using dr java i had to reformat the way i wrote the regex (i think). This is what I came up with: \\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}. its the same as yours but for some reason it wouldnt let me compile unless I added the extra \. Thanks for the help!